# How can I prove an ideal is a product of two irreducible ones

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I'm trying to solve this question:

[image]

I have a guess that $(6+\sqrt{11})=(2,4+\sqrt{11})(2,-3\sqrt{11})$ using some formulas in this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439845980) page 48. However I couldn't verify if the multiplication of these ideals are indeed equal to $(6+\sqrt{11})$ and prove they are primes.

If I'm wrong, what are the standard techniques I can use to solve this question?

I really need help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The norm of $6+\sqrt{11}$ is $N(6+\sqrt{11})=(6+\sqrt{11})(6-\sqrt{11})=25$. The factor ideals then can have norm ... ? By the way, $N(4+\sqrt{11})=5$ belongs to your first ideal as does $2$. Consequently $(2,4+\sqrt{11})=(1)$ is doubtful as a factor. A similar problem is there with your second factor, so I'm afraid it looks like something went wrong in your calculation.

Comment: I didn't understand how you get $(2,4+\sqrt{11})=(1)$.

Comment: If $I=(2,4+\sqrt{11})$, then $$1=(-2)\cdot2+(4-\sqrt{11})\cdot(4+\sqrt{11})\in I.$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you're right, I'm wrong.

Comment: So you should identify the ideals of norm five, and check how you get the prescribed ideal from them. Beware of the units.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've just found: $4+\sqrt{11}$, $4-\sqrt{11}$, $-4+\sqrt{11}$ and $-4-\sqrt{11}$. all has norm $5$.

Comment: Good. Do observe that $x$ and $-x$ generate the same ideal. Also because $(10+3\sqrt{11})(10-3\sqrt{11})=1$, the numbers $u=10+3\sqrt{11}$ and $u^{-1}$ are units, so $x$ and $u^mx$ generate the same ideal for any exponent $m\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- $(10+3\sqrt{11})(10-3\sqrt{11})=1$.
- $(4-\sqrt{11})^2(10+3\sqrt{11})=?$

Do interpret this in term of prime ideals and units.

Comment: The answer is $6+\sqrt{11}$, but this decomposition has an unit which is not prime.

Comment: @user42912: The units will always be there. When you factor (rational) integers you cannot get rid of the minus sign either! Thankfully the units can be ignored, when you look at ideals. So if $\mathfrak{I}=(6+\sqrt{11})$ and $\mathfrak{p}=(4-\sqrt{11})$, the required factorization into prime **ideals** is
$$\mathfrak{I}=\mathfrak{p}^2.$$ It's the same way with **ideals** of $\Bbb{Z}$. We have $(-6\Bbb{Z})=(2\Bbb{Z})\cdot (3\Bbb{Z})$.

Comment: Now, in order to prove $(4-\sqrt{11})$ is prime, I'm using the fact that $4-\sqrt{11}$ is a prime element (because its norm is prime) and then $(4-\sqrt{11})$ is a prime ideal. Am I right?

Comment: Correct. The principal ideal generated by an element with $\pm$ prime norm is always a prime. It gets a bit messier, when primes have inertia and/or are not principal.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me, you really helped me a lot. Just one question how did you get this factorization? was it by chance?

Comment: More or less by trial and error. We know that $(5)=\mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2$, with $\mathfrak{p}_1=(4+\sqrt{11}),\mathfrak{p}_2=(4-\sqrt{11})$, and these are the only prime ideals of $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$ that can occur in the factorization. Because $6+\sqrt{11}$ is not of the form $5$ times a unit, the factorization has to be either $\mathfrak{p}_1^2$ or $\mathfrak{p}_2^2$. I didn't guess correctly the first time :-)

Answer (score 2):

How you might approach it in a systematic way:

If $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})$, the norm of $(6+\sqrt{11})$ is $36-11 = 25$ so we know that $(6+\sqrt{11})$ is a product of prime ideals with norm dividing $5$. In general we need to look at how each rational prime dividing the norm of the element we're interested in ramifies in $K$, so here we need only examine $5$.

$11 = 3 \pmod{4}$ so we know that $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{11}]$. Then we can apply Dedekind's criterion to the polynomial $f(X)=X^2-11$ to factorise the ideal of any rational prime $p$, in particular, $p = 5$. (Why is this? Under what conditions can we apply Dedekind's criterion?)

Thus $\bar{f}(X)=X^2-1=(X-1)(X+1)\pmod{5}$ so $(5)=(5,1+\sqrt{11})(5,1-\sqrt{11})=P_1P_2$, say. For ideals in $\mathcal{O}_K$ for any number field $K$, $I|J$ is the same as $J \subset I$, so $P_2$ cannot divide $(6+\sqrt{11})$ else it would contain $2$, which is impossible since each prime ideal contains a unique rational prime.

This is a very general method, and I would say that understanding how it works gives a very useful tool in factorising ideals in many number fields.